# programatically add a *My Network Place* shortcut to sharepoint web folder

Tags: .net

I saw something in the framework to create a regular shortcut, but not a My Network Place shortcut to a file in a Sharepoint site on our intranet.

I found a kludge, but it doesn't always work for all folder names, not sure where it is failing. The kludge reverse engineers an existing shortcut rather than using a function for this purpose, if one exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://karlshifflett.wordpress.com/mole-for-visual-studio/http://www.microsoft.com/technet/scriptcenter/resources/qanda/may05/hey0509.mspx

Answer (score 1):

The UNC path to My Network Places is `%userprofile%\nethood`

Comment: Ok, thanks...But I am lookingfor a way to create a shortcut within the folder to a doc. That's still a useful tip, though, thx.